# JMeter ignore FATAL/OFF log levels

Tags: logging, jmeter, log4j2, slf4j

JMeter documentation ignore [FATAL/OFF log levels](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)

> Mapping to New Levels through SLF4J/Log4j2:
>
> DEBUG
>
> INFO
>
> WARN
>
> ERROR
>
> ERROR
>
> NONE

[Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html) and also [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) can support levels `FATAL` and `OFF`

> Standard log levels built-in to Log4J
>
> Standard Level intLevel
>
> OFF    0
>
> FATAL  100

`jmeter -LNONE` is ignored, and the following levels are working:

```
jmeter -LFATAL
```

or no logging:

```
jmeter -LOFF
```

Why OFF/FATAL is ignored in JMeter documentation although it seems to be working?

Can it fail to work in some cases? Or is docs not updated with logging changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [JMeter documentation](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/547) to reflect using `OFF` or `FATAL` and not `NONE`