# Can I set my jmeter to ignore some DEBUG errors?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm getting "ERROR o.a.j.e.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern:  blah b;ah blah " as one of my DEBUG ERRORS. Is it possible to set it to ignore or at least not to display any error in Jmeter Debug Logs?

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0):

You can turn [logging off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264142/jmeter-ignore-fatal-off-log-levels) by running JMeter as

```
  jmeter -LOFF
```

Or show only FATAL level

```
 jmeter -LFATAL
```