# log4j2.xml setting to disable logging in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to disable logging in JMeter 4.0. While executing any JMeter script it's generate logs as per the log level defined.

What should be the configuration in log4j2.xml so that it will not generate any logs?

Answer (score 2):

You can set JMeter log level as OFF to disable most of logging

```
jmeter -LOFF
```

Currently this is [not documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264142/jmeter-ignore-fatal-off-log-levels)

> OFF/FATAL is ignored in JMeter documentation although it seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

Just delete or rename `log4j2.xml` file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), on next start you will not see the log file.

Alternatively you can turn off the logging by changing the root logger value to `off` like:

```
<Root level="off">
  <AppenderRef ref="jmeter-log" />
  <AppenderRef ref="gui-log-event" />
</Root>
```

in this case jmeter.log file will be still generated but it will be empty.

More information:

- [Logging and error messages](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)